# Incorrect plural error messages with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

Using Rails 3.1.3. I have Accounts and Users. One Account can have many Users. I set this up using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305120/use-both-account-and-user-tables-with-devise/8529340#8529340).

I have a new.html.erb view that accepts data for one account and one user at the same time.  (The user's data goes into a "subform.")  The form works fine. However if there is an error, the messages for the subform's fields are pluralized, even though they should be singular. For example, I get

```
Users password doesn't match confirmation
Users password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
```

instead of

```
User password doesn't match confirmation
User password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
```

I don't think this is an inflection issue, since "User" follows standard pluralization rules. Rather it must have to do with the use of nested attributes in a subform.  In my case, the subform returns an array containing one user, but theoretically it could return data for multiple users.

How/where can I tell Rails not to pluralize when referring to only one element of an array?

---

**Edit 3/14/2012 to show controller and view:**

**app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb** ("New" action only):

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :user_signed_out,    :only   => [:new, :create]
  load_and_authorize_resource # CanCan - does a standard load for each action, and authorizes user

  def new
    # CanCan:  @account = Account.new (and tests each attribute for ability)
    @account.users.build
    @title = "Sign Up for a New Account"
    @header = "Sign up for a new account"
  end
end
```

**app/views/accounts/new.html.erb**:

```
<h2><%= @header %></h2>

<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'account_fields', :f => f %>

  <%= f.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :email %><br />
    <%= user_form.email_field :email %></div>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :password %><br />
    <%= user_form.password_field :password %></div>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= user_form.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create Account" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I was trying `error_messages_for` inside the `f.fields_for` block above.

**app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb** rendered by layout before all views:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> 
      prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %>
      from being saved:</h2>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Marc suggested, the messages are generated based on the model. This gets tricky when `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is involved, as it is in my Account model:

```rb
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

To get more insight into the error object, I inserted `<%= object.errors.inspect %>` into **_error_messages.html.erb**.  This showed me that the full error object is, for example:

> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb5c86a8 @base=#<Account id: nil, name: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
>   @messages={:"users.password"=>["doesn't match confirmation", "is too
>   short (minimum is 8 characters)"], :name=>["can't be blank"]}>

When Rails generates the [full_messages](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message) array, it just feeds each attribute and message into the [full_message](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message) method. If the attribute is "users.password", for example, then that will simply be "humanized" (without respect to the number of objects in the array) and concatenated with the message(s) to return

> Users password doesn't match confirmation
>   Users password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)

The crux of any solution is to avoid using full_messages:

- Although I couldn't get `error_messages_for` to work, it wouldn't be too
  hard to write a small helper that allows specifying a custom object
  name to prepend to the message.
- Avoid the problem of the displaying object name altogether by highlighting the
  specific field that is in error and placing the error message suffix(es) next
  to the field. This works nicely with Twitter Bootstrap and SimpleForm.
- [This article](http://adamhooper.com/eng/articles/5) make a good case for providing explicit
  translations for each message, claiming that any attempt to
  concatenate strings is bound to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because it's a `has_many` association. What you can do to override the object name that's render is to pass this option like so:

```
<%= error_messages_for @account, :object => [@account, :users], :object_name => 'Account' %>
```

This allows you to change that label to whatever you want for example:

```
<%= error_messages_for @account, :object => [@account, :users], :object_name => 'Profile' %>
```

Which then would look like

```
Profile password doesn't match confirmation
Profile password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Interesting idea, but it seems that f.error_messages was removed from Rails 3 so I wasn't able to test it. I've since added SimpleForm and Twitter Bootstrap, which puts a highlight box around the form field containing the error and adds only the suffix of the error text.  I.e. it's a workaround that avoids the issue by not actually naming the object.

Comment: Nope it's still available. the `f.` is the variable that's passed into your `form_for`. Try my edit above.

Comment: Okay I reverted my code to make sure I could duplicate the problem. Then I added `<%= error_messages_for @user, :object_name => 'User' %>` to the subform and got `undefined method 'error_messages_for' for #<#<Class:0xa273774>:0xa278328>`. This seems to confirm what I saw in several articles, e.g. [No more error_messages_for in Rails 3](http://www.suffix.be/blog/error-messages-for-rails3). Even if it did work, I didn't want to change it to "Profile", I just wanted to get it to do correct pluralization:  if there was only one user in the array, don't pluralize to "users".

Comment: Can I see the full _form.erb.html and your controller?

Comment: Added to original question. Also added the error_messages partial from which the `object.errors.full_messages` are displayed.

Comment: Updated answer. It wasn't working because the instance you were calling is `@account` and not `@user`. But now it'll validate both `@account` and the associated `:users` that's in the `fields_for`. Let me know how this goes. This should help though. Also check this out: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for

Comment: Actually it hits the undefined method _before_ the object, so with your updated code, I still get `undefined method 'error_messages_for' for #<#<Class:0x95974ec>:0xa3ef3f0>`. As it says at the top of the link you posted, "This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here." You see at the top of that page that everything from 3.0.0 onward is gray. Maybe you are using a plugin the recreates error_messages_for, e.g. [Dyanmic Form](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form)?

Comment: And it should be getting that error if you don't have it looking at the correct model. I'm not using any plugins that affect `error_messages_for`. It still works across all the versions.

Comment: Well for whatever reason, `error_messages_for` wasn't working for me, but the suggestion of using a helper method rather than `full_messages` is valid. I marked this as helpful, and outlined additional options in a separate answer.