# Devise Authentication with Accounts and Users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am working on implementing a top-level account that has many users.

I am working off the solution for this question:  [Use both Account and User tables with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305120/use-both-account-and-user-tables-with-devise)

What works:

After user submits registration form (below) the user and account is created as desired.

What doesn't work:

The user is not being authenticated before the redirect_to accounts_path.  In order to authenticate, the user must click login and enter the credentials they just signed up with.  Instead I need the user to be authenticated before the redirect.

I've been working on this for a few hours, tried a few approaches, but nothing seems to work.

Could someone help me with the code to authenticate the user after the user/account is successfully created.  THANKS!

**Models**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :inverse_of => :account, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  attr_accessible :name, :users_attributes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, :inverse_of => :users
  validates :account, :presence => true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :accounts, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
controllers/accounts_controller.rb
```

**Controllers**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.users.build # build a blank user or the child form won't display
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      flash[:success] = "Account created"
      redirect_to accounts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

**views/accounts/new.html.erb view**

```
<h2>Create Account</h2>

<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :email %><br />
    <%= user_form.email_field :email %></div>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :password %><br />
    <%= user_form.password_field :password %></div>
    <div class="field"><%= user_form.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= user_form.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create account" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually sign the user in. In the accounts controller you need a `sign_in(user)`, where `user` is the actual `User` model record that you want to sign in.

The problem with that is that you have a one account to many users relationship. Therefore, you'll need to get access to the single user somehow, e.g:

```
  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      sign_in(@account.users.first)
      flash[:success] = "Account created"
      redirect_to accounts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I pasted probably two dozen method / param combos right there but couldn't seem to get the right user.  This worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:new,:create]
```

to accounts controller in order to provide authentication to rest of the actions