# rails after_create not updating parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using the same approach obtained from this solution:

[Use both Account and User tables with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305120/use-both-account-and-user-tables-with-devise)

I am trying to update an owner_id column on the Account model, after the User has been saved:

#### Account Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_secure_token

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

#### User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :set_account_owner_id
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to  :account

  validates :name, :presence => true

  protected

  def set_account_owner_id
    self.account.owner_id = self.id
    self.account.save
  end

end
```

#### Accounts Controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    # Create a new Account and then update owner_id with User profile id
    @account = Account.new
    @account.users.build
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      flash[:success] = "Account successfully created!"
      redirect_to accounts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:name, :token, :token_flag, :owner_id, users_attributes: [:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role])
  end

end
```

#### Rspec Test

```
RSpec.describe Account, type: :model do
  it "should create an Account and a User through accepts_nested_attributes_for" do
    @accountuser = {
      :name => "My App Name",
      :users_attributes => [{
          :name     => "John Doe",
          :email    => "jdoe@email.com",
          :password => "password",
          :password_confirmation => "password",
          :role => "dev",
        }]
      }

    account = Account.create!(@accountuser)
    account.owner_id.should == account.users[0].id
  end
end
```

The test Fails with the following error:

```
1) Account should create an Account and a User through accepts_nested_attributes_for
     Failure/Error: account.owner_id.should == account.users[0].id
       expected: 1
            got: nil (using ==)
```

In reading other threads I thought that the issue was due to the fact I was not invoking 'save' in the after_create, however, I keep getting the same results.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: did you try passing `inverse_of` option on association definitions?

Comment: Worked. Thanks Dub I need to read more about that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `after_create` callback it's not guaranteed that you will have an id of record. Use `after_commit on: create` instead.

So, instead of calling `after_create :set_account_owner_id`, call:

```
after_commit :set_account_owner_id, on: :create
```

Also, remember to add the test_after_commit gem if you are testing code using after_commit. From the [after_commit doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit):

> Note that transactional fixtures do not play well with this feature.
>   Please use the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem to have these hooks fired in
>   tests.

Comment: Dub I'll try both suggestions and let you know.

Comment: Dub wanted to make sure you got credit. For those who are looking for some additional insight: http://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Comment: This got rid of a nasty bug that I was tracking elsewhere. For more on after_commit, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit